# What is the best way of sending many tls requests at once in Python?

Tags: python, ssl, simultaneous-calls

I'm trying to figure out which domains are blocked by a firewall. Let's say *sites* contains around 2 million domains.

Is ThreadPoolExecutor the fastest way for doing this or is there any faster method?

Thanks

```
import socket
import ssl
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

context = ssl.create_default_context()
socket.setdefaulttimeout(1)

sites = ['abc.com','def.com','geh.com']
def tls_check(domain):
    try:
        conn = ssl.create_connection(('1.1.1.1', 443))
    except socket.timeout:
        print(domain + "timed out")
        return
    except:
        return
    try:
        context.wrap_socket(conn, server_hostname=domain)
        conn.close()
    except ConnectionResetError:
        cx = open("blockedsites.txt", "a")
        cx.write("\n" + domain)
        cx.close()
        conn.close()
        return
    except:
        return
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as pool:
    pool.map(tls_check, sites)
```

Comment: If you're trying to figure out which domains are blocked then you don't even need to get as far as the TLS handshake, just try connecting with TCP and see if the connection succeeds. The TLS handshake is a significant CPU consumer and the nature of python threading (the dreaded GIL) means that this will be a significant bottleneck.

Comment: Unfortunately, the firewall seems to look at SNI in the ClientHello TLS Packet and send RST Packet right afterwards.

Comment: Is there a way to just send the ClientHello packet without full handshake?

Comment: I don't know of any python TLS libraries that are granular enough to specify just sending the client hello. You could create your own client hello packet manually. It would be a pain, but since you are just looking to see if the server is able to respond and you don't need to parse the server's response this is probably do-able.